# Rails 6 How to find element where association count is less than 2

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a problem with extracting data with one query. My two models looks like that:

```
# school.rb
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :meetings
end

# meetings.rb

class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school
  belongs_to :user
  
  # fields
  # status: [accepted, not_accepted, finished]
en
```

I want to take every `school` where passed `User` has less than 2 meetings with status `finished`. I was trying something like this:

```
School.joins(:meetings).where(meetings: { user: User, status: 'finished' }).group(:id).having( 'count(meetings.id) < 2')
```

But it works if `User` has one finished meeting in each school. I wonder if it is possible to solve this with one query? Maybe some of you knows if it is possible to do this and how?

@Edit
An example for easier understanding of what I would like to receive:

```
  School | User | Meeting
 1.  A   | Adam | finished 
 2.  A   | Adam | accepted
 3.  A   | Adam | finished
 4.  B   | Adam | accepted
 5.  C   | John | finished
 6.  D   |  -   |    -
 7.  E   | John | finished
```

So I want to create query which will returns school B, C, D and E for user `Adam`

Comment: doesn't it return exactly what you want? 1 meeting is in fact less than 2 meetings :)

Comment: Yep, but I want to find schools where he doesn't have any finished meeting too ;v

Comment: I wonder if moving the condition to `having` would work? `.where(meetings: { user: user })` and in having `(count(meetings.id) < 2 AND meetings.status = 'finished') OR meetings.status != 'finished'`

Comment: Unfortunately it won't work because query `School.joins(:meetings).where(meetings: { user: user})` returns schools where `User` has any meeting, so schools without meetings with passed `User` will not be returned

Comment: I thought that's what you wanted :D See if my answer works though

Comment: 0 meetings in `school` is still less than < 2 finished meetings, so I want to find schools where user doesn't have any meetings too :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to reverse your thinking here: get the schools you want to **EXCLUDE** from the results instead of trying to add extra ones to your query. Something like this:

```rb
# Get schools with more than 1 meeting for the user
excluded_schools = School.joins(:meetings)
  .where(meetings: { user: User, status: 'finished' })
  .group(:id)
  .having('count(meetings.id) > 1')

# Get ALL schools except for the ones you didn't want
filtered_schools = School.where.not(id: excluded_schools.select(:id))
```

Using `select(:id)` instead of `pluck(:id)` avoids triggering a new database query, so all of this should take just 1 database query when used inside a method. Of course in the console you'll have to nest these instead of storing in variables if you want to accomplish everything in 1 query.

Comment: won't it still only query schools that have meetings with finished status?

Comment: it won't work because if you use `left_joins` with `where` it will returns only rows where condition  `meetings: { user: User, status: 'finished' }` is `true`, schools where `User` doesn't have any meeting (which is less than < 2) will be not returned

Comment: Ah yes, that is indeed true, I misunderstood the problem a bit and made a careless recreation of it in my own database :D I'll update my answer shortly!

Comment: Updated my answer, @N0ne! Had to approach it from a different direction, otherwise it would've started to become quite complicated and hard to contain in just 1 query... This works in my database, with slightly different queries of course, but let me know if it doesn't work for you.